# Pass form data to spring controller by ajax; Always get 404 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I am trying to pass data from my .jsp to spring controller. But my ajax call always gives error.

I tried whether the data is being caught by alert and console.log, it is fine. I am having errors with my ajax call / controller I guess.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"/save",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "registrationNumber" : regNo,
        "GPAYearI" : gpaI,
        "GPAYearII" : gpaII
    }),

    success: function(){
        alert('Saved');
    }, error: function (response) {
        console.log("Error occurred: " + response.responseText);
    }
});
```

and this is my controller,

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @PostMapping("save")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createCase(@RequestBody StudentDTO studentDTO){
        Student studentCase = new Student();
        studentCase.setRegistrationNumber(studentDTO.getRegistrationNumber());
        studentCase.setGPAYearI(studentDTO.getGPAYearI());
        studentCase.setGPAYearII(studentDTO.getGPAYearII());

        studentRepository.save(studentCase);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(studentCase.getRegistrationNumber(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

I have the same entities in the StudentDTO as well.

```
Error occurred: {"timestamp":"2019-08-26T14:08:29.460+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/save"} student.js:51:21
```

Above is the message I've got.

I want to know where I've done mistake.

Comment: Could you use Chrome develoment console or Firebug to review the data sent to controller?

Comment: Do you have any `server.servlet.context-path` in an application file. Are you able to call other endpoints of StudentController

Comment: @PatelRomil I tried with Get Mapping, it didn't work. same 404 error came in response.

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa I worked with that, since I am not familiar with that I am trying to sort it out.

Comment: The message you got is generated by Spring. There are many possibilities: incorrect path, parameters sent cannot be parsed to StudentDTO object and Spring understand that method controller is needed, etc. Could you paste the request sent by your browser?